# What in my code is causing this error (NSMutableArray is to small for the object being called)?

Tags: iphone, arrays, memory, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am assuming that somewhere in my code the objects in the array are being removed faster than they are created. I have been looking for the problem for over an hour so please help!

Here is the error:`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 7 beyond bounds [0 .. 6]'`
Thanks in advance and here is my code:

```
- (void)onTimer {
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    imgView.image = particleImg;
    imgView.frame = CGRectMake(kViewDimensions/2, kViewDimensions/2, startSize.width, startSize.height);
    [self addSubview:imgView];
    [particlesArray addObject:imgView];
    [imgView release];
    moveTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(moveObjs) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
- (void)moveObjs {
    for (int i = 0; i < [particlesArray count]; i++) {
        animID = @"MoveId";
        UIImageView *imgV = [particlesArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        CGPoint randPoint = CGPointMake(arc4random()%kMaxRandX, arc4random()%kMaxRandY);
        imgV.center = CGPointMake(randPoint.x, randPoint.y);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        animValue = i;
        num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:animValue];
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3 target:self selector:@selector(animationEnded) userInfo:num repeats:NO];
        NSLog(@"\n %d",animValue);
    }
}
- (void)animationEnded {   
    int av = [num intValue];
    UIImageView *iv = [particlesArray objectAtIndex:av];
    if ([animID isEqualToString:@"MoveId"]) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
        iv.alpha = 0.0f;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [particlesArray removeObjectAtIndex:av];
    }
    else {
        [iv removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attempting to trigger a method at the end of your animation with a timer is ill-advised. Instead, you should be using the `setAnimationDidStopSelector:` class method within your animation block. On top of that, because of the way you are using num to handle removing objects from the array, you are guaranteed to exceed the bounds of the array at some point during one of the invocations of animationEnded. It would be better to reference the object itself, rather than its position in the array. This is what the context parameter in the `beginAnimations:context:` method is for:

```
- (void)moveObjs {
    for (int i = 0; i < [particlesArray count]; i++) {
        animID = @"MoveId";

        UIImageView *imgV = [particlesArray objectAtIndex:i];

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:imgV];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];

        CGPoint randPoint = CGPointMake(arc4random()%kMaxRandX, arc4random()%kMaxRandY);
        imgV.center = CGPointMake(randPoint.x, randPoint.y);

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {   
    UIImageView *iv = (UIImageView *)context;

    if ([animID isEqualToString:@"MoveId"]) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
        iv.alpha = 0.0f;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [particlesArray removeObject:iv];
    } else {
        [iv removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

NOTE: If you are not supporting versions prior to iOS 4, then you should switch to using the new Blocks based methods, such as `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:`.

Answer (score 0):

In animationEnded, you're attempting to remove image #7 7 times, I believe.

EDIT: a little more information...

You loop through each image (0...n) in moveObjs, re-assigning 'num' in each iteration with a new value. So on the last iteration (which, based on the error, I'm assuming i=7, for a total of 8 images), num is left at 7.

When the animations end, animationEnded is called, num is turned back into an int (av), and the element at index 'av' is removed.

Comment: Oops I forgot to include this I'm sorry about that but I forgot to include this line of code:                        - (void)startEmitting {
    generateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

Comment: Still, the problem is in the assignment of 'num', and the removal of the elements - you're always removing element #7, as illustrated by Paul.s's answer.

Comment: OK - I didn't see that you passed 'num' - still, there's a problem with removing elements... I'm going to look something up, then I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much but I see what you wrote and it is true do you know how I would go about fixing it because depending on the timer the interval their can be a varying number of total images

Answer (score 0):

If you put an `NSLog` in the `animationEnded` method like this

```
- (void)animationEnded 
{   
    int av = [num intValue];
    NSLog(@"index => %i", av);

    // more stuff
}
```

You will see that for each run it will log out the highest number that results from your loop which is 7.

So first time round removing object at index 7 is fine, but then on the second time you are removing index 7 again when there are only [0 .. 6] items